# Convert String to Html format

Tags: java, android, html, xml, jsp

I'm a beginner mobile developer for Android/iPhone.
I use JAVA to place a request for a message to the back end (DB/Mainframe) and I get response in proper expected format(In Paragraphs). 
And I redirect this response to a JSP page. However, by the time it reaches this page it gets all crumbled into one single paragraph.
So in my front end device I'm not getting the message in the proper format.
I want the message in the JSP to be in HTML format, containing `<Br>` or new line (Or whatever it is) whenever there is a break in paragraph or line change.

```
for(int i=0;i<messageList.size();i++){
MsgCenterDetail msg=(MsgCenterDetail)messageList.get(i);
MsgCenterDetail newmsg=new MsgCenterDetail();
**newmsg.setMsgBody(msg.getMsgBody());**
}
```

The newMsg object(Last line) is what i forward to the JSP. What i'm saying is, when I Print what i'm setting in it(ie,msg.getMsgBody()) on the debug console i get it in paragraphs. But in the JSP page i get it all jumbled into one huge paragraph.

Can someone tell me how to do this ?

Comment: have you need html format in jsp or android?

Comment: Why is the string losing its newlines in the redirect?

Comment: I need it in my JSP. My JSP needs to display the HTMl Tags

Answer (score 1):

Put `<p><pre>` tags around your content before redirecting it to your JSP page. So the content you will send to your JSP will be

```
<p><pre> ... all your content ... </pre></p>
```

Here `<p>` denotes a HTML Paragraph and `<pre>` is html preserve tag which preserves all the spaces in the content inside this tag. you can visit [HTML tag reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/) for more details.

Hope this resolve your issue.

Comment: Can you elaborate more. I don't know what these <p><Pre> tags do. Sorry if its a very silly question.

Answer (score 0):

Put seperators such as  '|' at the end of every line.
So when the code comes to the jsp page in paragraphs it will be there with the '|'

so you can just use str_replace and replace it with a `<br/>` or whatever else you might use.

Give it a try :D

Comment: You're getting there man. But the thing is these messages that come are not put by me. So i can't use custom seperators. I want JAVA to detect a break in line by itself and then replace it with <br>.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(data)));  // where data contains string with html tags like <br>,<b>,<i>,etc.
```